# Program in $PATH does not does not run when called

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, mint

I've created a program, a calculator named `eval`, and it works fine when run from a local directory (e.g. `./eval`). In my home directory, I've created a bin file and added it to the $PATH environment variable. In doing so, I'm easily able to call the programs I've made just by typing their name (e.g. `eval`). The problem is, however, that whilst my terminal recognizes the program, it doesn't run. What could be the problem?

**Output**

```bsh
cupric@linux-mint:~/bin$ rmexky
rmexky: invalid # of arguments
Try 'rmexky -h' for more information.
cupric@linux-mint:~/bin$ eval
cupric@linux-mint:~/bin$ !!
eval
cupric@linux-mint:~/bin$ ./eval
> 2+2
chk_syntax
single: 0   double: 0   chr: 2
single: 0   double: 0   chr: +
single: 1   double: 0   chr: 2

evaluate
2+2
4

4
> 
cupric@linux-mint:~/bin$
```

Terminal: GNOME Terminal

Distro: Linux Mint Ulyssa

Comment: `eval` is an unfortunate choice - it is the name of a bash shell builtin command

Comment: After taking the program out of the bin and calling eval on its own, I see your point. I suppose I should change the name of the program. Thanks!

Comment: We don't support Linux Mint at this website. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

`eval` happens to be the same name of a builtin bash command, as @steeldriver pointed out. It had nothing to do with my method of running the program. Rather, it was because I was running the bash command instead.